# Correcting a broken ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am getting to grips with the constraint layout, so far, finding things a bit, unusual!

This is my effort so far :

[image]

This is laid out in the way I want it.

At runtime, things get interesting to say the least:

[image]

The XML for the Layout is:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="my.first.FFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/boxStatusLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:text="Status: "
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/boxStatusField"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/boxStatusField"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="176dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:text="Unknown"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastContactLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Last Contacted Time:"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/lastContactField"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/boxStatusLabel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastContactField"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:text="Not made contact"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/homeLine1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/systemInUseNameField"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="No system running"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeLine1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/systemInUseImage"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/systemInUseImage"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeLine1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/systemInUseLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="What's running:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeLine1" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Can somebody correct my XML, which I can load back into my Android Studio to study to understand why my attempt is wrong? An explanation of my mistakes when putting together the constraint layout would also help.

Comment: It is actually.

Comment: OK. What are those warning signs saying? Usually they advice of what's wrong

Comment: Its about string internationalisation - none are relevant

Comment: Weird... I ran your XML as it is and shows fine. Is your activity extending `AppCompatActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how it looks at my device:
[image: this is how it looks at my device]

show your class which is inflating this layout ? (either MainActivity or Fragment).

Also I would advice to set layout_width to non zero.

**EDIT:**
we talked via IRC to resolve issue. Things we checked:
 1. extending AppCompatActivity and android.support.v4.app.Fragment
 2. final problem was in main_activity.xml with  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

FragmentManager.replace() wont work like this. Please mark as correct and closed.

Comment: You pretty much helped me find the issue, answer  being posted

Comment: Marking as correct and closed - thank you. My answer below gives more specific details of the specific fix

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of hardcoded size in there... Your parent FrameLayout is also useless.

Try this one:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/boxStatusLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Status: "
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/boxStatusField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Unknown"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lastContactLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastContactLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Last Contacted Time:"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/boxStatusLabel"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastContactField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Not made contact"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lastContactLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/boxStatusLabel"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/homeLine1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/systemInUseNameField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="No system running"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/systemInUseLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/systemInUseLabel"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/systemInUseImage"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeLine1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/systemInUseLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="What's running:"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeLine1"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This helped - removing unnecessary FrameLayout, but was not the main problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the main activity xml. My question's XML was within a Fragment.

This Fragment belongs in a FrameLayout which had incorrect width and height.

I changed my main activity.xml layout from :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text="Title bbb"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

</FrameLayout>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text="Title bbb"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

</FrameLayout>
```

Notice the changed params on the layout_width and layout_height on the FrameLayout. This was squashing my Fragment contents :)